# How to set Etag when returning Custom Objects in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, etag, last-modified

I want to setup Etag and Last-Modified header for my APIs. Currently my APIs are returning Objects (say a Person object).
I have searched the Web but couldn't find a way to implement Etags without using ResponseBuilder.
Is it possible to do the same?

Can someone point me as to how to implement Etag header setting in Jersey.

Following is the Structure of my API:

```
@POST
@Path("/person/{gateway}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public PersonResponse initiate(@PathParam("gateway") String gateway, PersonRequest request, @Context Request req, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws WebException {
  PersonResponse personResponse = paymentService.getPersonResponse(request, gateway);
  EntityTag etag = new EntityTag(((Integer)(personResponse.hashCode())).toString());
  if (req.evaluatePreconditions(etag) != null) {
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ETAG, etag.getValue());
  }
  return (purchaseResponse);
}
```

Is above code the right way to implement Etag headers. Also how to add Last-Modified header to the same. Should this be a custom implementation or Jersey provides some automatic functionality.